# Unexpected MemoryStream behavior

Tags: c#

I am reading and writing to the same MemoryStream.

Something like this(possible compilation mistakes):

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write("1234",0,4);
stream.Position -= 4;
stream.Read(buffer,0,4);
```

Why do I HAVE to move Position? Why it is not separate to read and write?

Is there any other Stream that can be used?

Comment: You have to move the position because that's how a stream works, when you read or write the position moves, so if you want to read or write the same section twice you have to move the position back to the beginning. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Note that this code won't even compile, as there's no overload for `Stream.Write` which takes a string...

Comment: Actually, *all* streams have a position that moves each time you read or write. I suspect this holds for all languages too, as this is part of the definition of the stream: a sequence of data with a current position which you move forward by reading/writing

Comment: @Ben Robinson I use it as a queue. Ideal option is a Queue<byte>, but then I need to put the data one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's how streams are supposed to work. You have *one* position, see it as a cursor, set at a point in the stream at which you can read or write. Reading and writing both advance this position.

If you're merely using a `MemoryStream` to exchange data between callers, as a pseudo IPC mechanism, then perhaps some better way exists to do so.

Comment: What is the pseudo IPC mechanism?

Comment: I say _if_. Can you explain why you're using streams like this?

Comment: It is a very old code written on C#2 that I am trying accurately rewrite step by step. Initially it is used as a buffer to store incoming data from the server till the GUI will have a time to process it. The data is binary.